# Where to place images and tables for a good layout?

Tags: floats, positioning, typography

I use KOMA Script which always places images in the top of the page. I don't think that this always looks nicely, but if I change the place of my images it doesn't seem much better. Unfortunately I couldn't find any guidelines concerning the proper placement of images and tables with latex. Could you provide me with some tips for a good layout?

Comment: scrartcl sets `\newcommand*{\fps@figure}{tbp}` so allowing top bottom and page float figures by default, I don't see anything that forces top floats.

Comment: This seems to be a general typographical question.  In fact, where to put pictures is one problem, and how to achieve it in LaTeX is another.

Answer (score 3):

If you can read German you should have a look on page 255 ff in the book "Lesetypografie", ISBN 3-87439-652-5. It shows on several pages how you can use images in a good looking way.  I do not know an English book, sorry.

I think that KOMA-Script does (if you let it) a good job with the positions of the images.  If you want to choose the position by your own I would suggest to use the position at the beginning of the page. A big image at the end of the page could give you the feeling, that the page is larger than the others, it looks "heavy".

My English is not so good, I hope I made me clear.